# Statement execution order not followed in gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to transfer file names from Android application variants to Maven publication artifacts. The construct in my build.gradle is:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      groupId android.defaultConfig.applicationId
      artifactId 'apk'
      version = project.ext.version

      artifacts = {
        def list = []
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
           variant.outputs.each { output ->
              list.add (output.outputFile.absolutePath)    
              println "Output " + output.outputFile.absolutePath + " list " + list
           }
        }    
        println "To deploy " + list
        list.iterator()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No artifacts are ever deployed with this script, and it produces the output that looks like a raise of machines:

```
To deploy []
Output B:\ox\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-1.0.apk list [B:\ox\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-1.0.apk]                        
Output B:\ox\app\build\outputs\apk\app-release-1.0.apk list [B:\ox\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-1.0.apk, B:\ox\app\build\outputs\apk\app-release-1.0.apk]
```

So all files were nicely iterated through, but for some reason the last print statement runs before the terminal print statement, and all construct just returns the empty list.

Why does this happen, and how to fix this? I need to set the list of iterated files and the artifacts property for Maven publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is a declarative language,  so order of statements is not important.  The builds are executed in following way:

1) script is evaluated in order it's written.  That's how Gradle find out about what tasks you have in your script and which plugins to load.   Not that tasks themselves are not executed at that point.

2) Then Gradle constructs a DAG of all the tasks that need to be executed.  Each task can declare dependencies which are the tasks that must be executed beforehand.

3) After DAG is constructed,  the tasks are run.  The tasks are run according to their declared dependencies.  Tasks with no dependencies are run first, possibly in parallel.  The tasks that had dependencies are scheduled to run after all their predecessors have finished.  Again if possible Gradle will run things in parallel.

3a) Tasks themseleves are run in following order.  First  doFirst {} blocks are executed,  then the task body and after that the doLast {} blocks.

So in your case if you want to compose the list of artifacts, you should enclose your iterator into doFirst {} block.